# Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied argument

Tags: floating-point, integer, double, swift, multiplication

I have converted a `String` to an `Int` by by using `toInt()`. I then tried multiplying it by 0.01, but I get an error that says `Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied argument.` Here is my code:

```
var str: Int = 0
var pennyCount = 0.00

str = pennyTextField.text.toInt()!
pennyCount = str * 0.01
```

From reading other posts it seems that the answer has to do with the type. For example if the type is set as an Integer then it gets a similar error. I have tried changing the type to an Int, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I have also tried setting the type for 'str' and 'pennyCount' as `Floats` and `Doubles` and all combinations of `Floats`, `Doubles`, and `Ints`. My guess is the the problem has to do with `toInt()` function's conversion of a `String` to an `Integer`.

Could someone help clarify what the issue may be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Swift seems to be fairly picky about implied type casting, so in your example you're multiplying str (an Integer) by 0.01 (a Double) so to resolve the error, you'll need to cast it like this:

```
var str: Int = 0
var pennyCount = 0.00
str = pennyTextField.text.toInt()!
pennyCount = Double(str) * 0.01
```